# clearInterval button not stopping setInterval countdown

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, countdown, clearinterval

The idea is to make a simple js countdown with minutes and seconds, showing the numbers in a html doc, with a button to start/continue and another to stop/pause. I got stuck on seconds at pausing the time...The Start button works, but I can't seem to figure out why Stop doesn't work. I've read multiple similar questions trying fixes but still same result. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

```js
var min = 5;
var sec = 60;
var secoutput;
 
document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = min;
if (sec >= 60)
 {document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "00";}
else
 {document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = secoutput; }
   
function start(){
var secoutput = setInterval(function(){
 sec-=1;
    document.getElementById("sec").textContent = sec;
    if(sec <= 0)
        clearInterval (secoutput);
    },1000);
}

function stop(){
        clearInterval (secoutput);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    
<p id="min"></p>
<p id="sec"></p>
```

Comment: You *redeclared* `secoutput` in the `start()` function. Drop the `var` there.

Comment: You're using `var secoutput` inside of your `start`, so you're redefining a `secoutput` var scoped inside of your `start` method. The global `secoutput` is never assigned anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you declare `var secoutput = setInterval(function(){` inside of the `start()` function. Because of this the declaration you can not access that specific variable outside of your `start()` function. if you simply remove the `var` declaration and only have a `secoutput = setInterval(function(){` then your code will work. You can learn more about closures in JavaScript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var min = 5;
var sec = 60;
var secoutput;
 
document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = min;
if (sec >= 60)
 {document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "00";}
else
 {document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = secoutput; }
   
function start(){
    // Removed the var so the original variable is used
    secoutput = setInterval(function(){
 sec-=1;
    document.getElementById("sec").textContent = sec;
    if(sec <= 0)
        clearInterval (secoutput);
    },1000);
}

function stop(){
        clearInterval (secoutput);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    
<p id="min"></p>
<p id="sec"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your start() function, where you've re-declared the secoutput variable. Just change this:

```
var secoutput = setInterval(function(){ ... }
```

to this:

```
secoutput = setInterval(function(){ ... }
```